# How do I prove this combinatorics formula? $ 3^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k $

Tags: combinatorics

I am stuck on trying to prove this combinatorics question. The question reads:

*Prove that for any positive integer n,*
$$
3^n = \sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}2^k
$$
Does anyone know how to begin/prove this? Thank you!